# How do you solve a system of linear equations over a finite field using Sympy?

Tags: python, linear-algebra, sympy

Please provide a working example with at least two variables. I can't seem to find out how to do this from the documentation.

I have tried:

```
solve(Eq(poly(x + y,domain=FF(7)),0),x,y)
```

but this outputs

```
[]
```

which is incorrect and appears to be a type issue. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> solve(Poly(x + y,domain=FF(7)),[x,y])
[{x: -y}]
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: This is just a question of syntax.  The shibboleth indicates that your choice of username is sound.

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9821 solve doesn't fully support solving linear systems over finite fields.